# Sending an integer serially in Arduino

Tags: integer, char, byte, arduino, serial-communication

I need to send an integer, say between 0-10000, to Arduino using serial communication. What's the best way of doing that?

I can think of breaking the number into an character array *(eg: 500 as '5','0','0')* and sending them as a byte stream (yeah, that's ugly). Then reconstruct at the other end. (anything is sent serially as a byte stream, right?)

Isn't there a better way? Somehow, it should be able to assign the value into an `int` type variable.

*(really need to know the same thing about strings too, if possible)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If what you're looking for is speed, then instead of sending an ASCII encoded int, you can divide your number into two bytes, here's an example:

```cpp
uint16_t number = 5703;               // 0001 0110 0100 0111
uint16_t mask   = B11111111;          // 0000 0000 1111 1111
uint8_t first_half   = number >> 8;   // >>>> >>>> 0001 0110
uint8_t sencond_half = number & mask; // ____ ____ 0100 0111
    
Serial.write(first_half);
Serial.write(sencond_half);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify the *from* environment, so I assume your troubles is with reading serial data on an Arduino?

Anyways, as can be seen in the [Arduino Serial reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/serial), you can read an integer using the `Serial.parseInt()` method call. You can read strings with eg. `Serial.readBytes(buffer, length)` but your real issue is to know when to expect a string and when to expect an integer (and what to do if something else comes along, eg. noise or so...)

Comment: Well, the _from_ environment can be considered as PC. But since it's serial communication that sender won't matter, eh? (Ultimately, i'm trying to use this in wireless communication, with [APC220](http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=57#.UMsDR-TYfH8)). Anyway, thanks. Honestly, i wonder why i didn't see that before. I'll give a try.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```cpp
unsigned int number = 0x4142; //ASCII characters 'AB';
char *p;
    
p = (char*) &number;
    
Serial.write(p,2);
```

will return 'BA' on the console (LSB first).

Answer (score 1):

Other way:

```cpp
char p[2];
*p = 0x4142; //ASCII characters 'AB'
Serial.write(p,2);
```

I like this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not from coding background, today i was trying the same and got it working.. I am just sending the number byte wise with start and end bytes added ('a' and 'b'). hope it helps..`enter code here`

```cpp
//sending end
unsigned char a,n[4],b;
int mynum=1023;// the integer i am sending
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    n[i]='0'+mynum%10; // extract digit and store it as char
    mynum=mynum/10;
}

SendByteSerially(a);
_delay_ms(5);
SendByteSerially(n[3]);
_delay_ms(5);
SendByteSerially(n[2]);
_delay_ms(5);
SendByteSerially(n[1]);
_delay_ms(5);
SendByteSerially(n[0]);
_delay_ms(5);
SendByteSerially(b);
_delay_ms(100);


//at receiving end. 
while(portOne.available() > 0) 
{
    char inByte = portOne.read();
    if(inByte!='a' && inByte !='b')
    {
    Serial.print(inByte);
    }
    else if(inByte ='a')
        Serial.println();
    else if(inByte ='b')
        Serial.flush();
    }
delay(100);
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP describes as 'ugly' and wants to avoid.